# regex to extract a text

Tags: python, regex

regex to find the text

```
string = '<a href="/naruto/700">Naruto 700</a> : Naruto Uzumaki!!</td>'
```

output that i desire

```
[("/naruto/700", "Naruto 700", "Naruto Uzumaki!!")]
```

regex i am using `re.compile(r'"(.*?)">(.*?)<*:(.*?)<')`

result i am getting `[('/naruto/700', 'Naruto 700</a> ', ' Naruto Uzumaki!!')]`

i don't want to iterate over it again to split it

how can i remove `</a>` tag here.

thanks

Comment: i want to use regex here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this :

```
\"(.*?)\">(.*?)<.*:(.*?)<
```

Answer (score 1):

Just using

```
r'\<a href\=\"(.*?)\"\>(.*?)\<\/a\> \: (.*?)\<\/td\>'
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/TyGKaQ/1